Generating ordered n-tuples with k distinct elements
I need to generate all integers such that they start with 1, have exactly k distinct digits, and every next digit is at most by 1 larger than the maximum of the preceding ones (10 is replaced with 0). At the moment I am using the following recursive function:
TotalDigits=10;
DistinctDigits=4;
b[n_, m_] := 
  b[n, m] = 
   If[n == 1, {{1}}, 
    Table[Append[#, Mod[i, 10]], {i, 1, Min[Max[#] + 1, m]}] & /@ 
      b[n - 1, m] // Flatten[#, 1] &];
FromDigits /@ 
  Select[b[TotalDigits, DistinctDigits], 
   CountDistinct[#] == DistinctDigits &]

This works when the number of distinct digits is small but becomes very ineffective when it gets larger, as too many unnecessary elements are generated that are later filtered out by the Select function. Can anyone suggest how to optimize this so that I do not need to generate too many elements at the intermediate step? In particular, b[10,10] should return only one element, {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}, but my current code runs out of memory before it can calculate this.
I saw a somewhat related question here: Generating Tuples with restrictions
However, I doubt that the solution proposed there, which uses IntegerPartitions, is of any use in my case, because the sum is not constrained.

you could search for dfs

a ref implement in py, https://pastebin.com/622JbvWp, I am porting it to mathematica.

len = 10;
k = 10;
dfs[number_List] := If[Length[number] == len ,
   If[
       Length[Union[If[# < 10, #, 0] & /@ number]] == k,
       Print[If[# < 10, #, 0] & /@number]
   ],
  Do[
    If[i <= 10,
      dfs[Append[number, i]]
      ],
      {i, {Last[number], Last[number] + 1}}
    ]
  ];

dfs[{1}]


{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}


Thank you! This is indeed much faster, though I don't quite understand how it works. ;-)

I just realized that I made a mistake in my problem statement, therefore I edited it. Every next digit should be at most by 1 larger than the maximum of the preceding digits, sorry for this mistake. My old description did not match the code.

@Vosoni change to {i, Range[0, Last[number] + 1]}  in Do, but it will print one more dup result.

It should be {i, Range[1, Last[number] + 1]} because zero comes at the end, then it works.

Or, rather, {i, Range[1, Last[Union[number]] + 1]}

This is the version of the code in the form of a function: Patterns[len_, k_] := (    Clear[dfs];    ResultingPatterns = {};    dfs[number_List] := If[Length[number] == len,      If[Length[Union[If[# < 10, #, 0] & /@ number]] == k,        AppendTo[ResultingPatterns, If[# < 10, #, 0] & /@ number]],       Do[If[i <= 10, dfs[Append[number, i]]], {i,         Range[1, Last[Union[number]] + 1]}]      ];    dfs[{1}];    FromDigits /@ ResultingPatterns    ); Patterns[11, 10]

Patterns[11, 10] returns 55 results, as it should. Thanks a lot for help.

I'll post here a slightly modified code suggested by AsukaMinato which achieves what I wanted:
Patterns[len_, k_] := (Clear[dfs];
ResultingPatterns = {};
dfs[number_List] := If[Length[number] == len,
If[Length[Union[If[# < 10, #, 0] & /@ number]] == k,
AppendTo[ResultingPatterns, If[# < 10, #, 0] & /@ number]],
Do[If[i <= 10, dfs[Append[number, i]]], {i, Range[1, Last[Union[number]] + 1]}]];
dfs[{1}];
FromDigits /@ ResultingPatterns);
Patterns[11, 10]

